# Exclude all records if 1 occurrence is currently effective

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table called '`Events`' that stores information about an event including effective start and end dates. The event can happen multiple times over time. I need to exclude all records of a given event if that event is currently effective. In my example below I only want to return a single value of 'Olympics' as that is the only event that is NOT active on today's date (today being 10/11/16 as I write this).

```
╔═══════════╦════════════╦════════════╗
║   Event   ║   Start    ║    End     ║
╠═══════════╬════════════╬════════════╣
║ World Cup ║ 1/07/2016  ║ 15/07/2016 ║
║ Olympics  ║ 15/08/2016 ║ 25/08/2016 ║
║ World Cup ║ 1/09/2016  ║ 15/09/2016 ║
║ Olympics  ║ 15/09/2016 ║ 25/09/2016 ║
║ Olympics  ║ 15/10/2016 ║ 25/10/2016 ║
║ World Cup ║ 1/11/2016  ║ 15/11/2016 ║
║ World Cup ║ 1/12/2016  ║ 15/12/2016 ║
╚═══════════╩════════════╩════════════╝
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT distinct Event
FROM tableName WHERE Event NOT IN (SELECT Event 
                                   FROM tableName
                                   WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),GETDATE(),103) BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate
                                  )
```

Comment: This will return duplicated records.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick.

```
SELECT DISTINCT event
FROM table
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM table
    WHERE GETDATE() >= start 
    AND GETDATE()<= end
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will work and give you answer that you want:
only event that is NOT active on today's date: Output is 'Olympics'

```
SELECT Top 1 [Event] FROM Events WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),GETDATE(),103) 
NOT BETWEEN [Start] AND [End]
```

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me using MySQL, change some macros and it should work the same for SQL server.

```
SELECT event,count(event)
FROM table_name
WHERE event NOT IN (
    SELECT event
    FROM table_name
    WHERE start <= NOW() AND end >= NOW()
    GROUP BY event
);
```

Converting the macros you would get something like: (not tested)

```
SELECT event,count(event)
FROM table_name
WHERE event NOT IN (
    SELECT event
    FROM table_name
    WHERE start <= GETDATE() AND end >= GETDATE()
    GROUP BY event
);
```

this gives you a count also but you can remove the `,count(event)` part.

This is the output I got based on the data you provided:

```
+----------+--------------+
| event    | count(event) |
+----------+--------------+
| Olympics |            3 |
+----------+--------------+
```